# How do i get the factor to index mappings from RFormula/RFormulaModel in Apache Spark?

Tags: r, model, formula, apache-spark-mllib, pipeline

All,

I have a simple data frame like below

[image]

I am using RFormula api to make a model matrix as below

```
val formula = "dep ~ indep"
val rF = new RFormula().setFormula(formula).setFeaturesCol("features").setLabelCol("label")
val rfModel = rF.fit(df)
```

where rfModel is of type RFormulaModel. According to the docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/RFormulaModel.html)

the mapping of the categorical variable "indep" should be available for access from this object as pipelineModel but this seems to be a private member.

My question is how do i get the labels and corresponding indices from the RFormulaModel object? I know I can use the metadata of the transformed dataframe and do string manipulation but is there a straightforward way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with a hack where I had to write the RFormulaModel to the disk and then read the pipelineModel part back in as PipelineModel. From there I have access to the StringIndexerModel stages as shown here

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel

rfModel.write.overwrite.save("/rfModel")
val pModel = PipelineModel.read.load("/rfModel/pipelineModel")

val strIndexers = pModel.stages.filter(stage => stage.isInstanceOf[StringIndexerModel])
val labelMaps = strIndexers.map(e  => { val i = e.asInstanceOf[StringIndexerModel]; (i.getInputCol, i.labels)})
```

Answer (score 0):

In pyspark you can extract the metadata from the target dataframe like

```
for attr in df.schema["X"].metadata["ml_attr"]["attrs"]["numeric"]:
    print(f"idx: {attr['idx']}, name: {attr['name']}")
```

Hope this is applicable in scala as well!